# Slurmd remains inactive/failed on start

Tags: cluster, slurm

I currently have a cluster of 10 worker nodes managed by Slurm with 1 master node. I have previously successfully set up the cluster, after some teething problems, but managed to get it working. I put all my scripts and instructions on my GitHub repo, here:

https://brettchapman.github.io/Nimbus_Cluster

I recently needed to start over again to increase hard drive space, and now can't seem to install and configure it correctly no matter what I've tried.

Slurmctld and slurmdbd install and are configured correctly (both active and running with the systemctl status command), however slurmd remains in a failed/inactive state.

The following is my slurm.conf file:

## slurm.conf file generated by configurator.html.

## Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.

## See the slurm.conf man page for more information.

SlurmctldHost=node-0
#SlurmctldHost=

#DisableRootJobs=NO
#EnforcePartLimits=NO
#Epilog=
#EpilogSlurmctld=
#FirstJobId=1
#MaxJobId=999999
#GresTypes=
#GroupUpdateForce=0
#GroupUpdateTime=600
#JobFileAppend=0
#JobRequeue=1
#JobSubmitPlugins=1
#KillOnBadExit=0
#LaunchType=launch/slurm
#Licenses=foo*4,bar
#MailProg=/bin/mail
#MaxJobCount=5000
#MaxStepCount=40000
#MaxTasksPerNode=128
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-#
#PluginDir=
#PlugStackConfig=
#PrivateData=jobs
ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
#Prolog=
#PrologFlags=
#PrologSlurmctld=
#PropagatePrioProcess=0
#PropagateResourceLimits=
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=
#RebootProgram=
ReturnToService=1
#SallocDefaultCommand=
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
#SrunEpilog=
#SrunProlog=
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm-llnl
SwitchType=switch/none
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/cgroup
#TaskPluginParam=
#TaskProlog=
#TopologyPlugin=topology/tree
#TmpFS=/tmp
#TrackWCKey=no
#TreeWidth=
#UnkillableStepProgram=
#UsePAM=0

## TIMERS

#BatchStartTimeout=10
#CompleteWait=0
#EpilogMsgTime=2000
#GetEnvTimeout=2
#HealthCheckInterval=0
#HealthCheckProgram=
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
#MessageTimeout=10
#ResvOverRun=0
MinJobAge=300
#OverTimeLimit=0
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=600
#UnkillableStepTimeout=60
#VSizeFactor=0
Waittime=0

## SCHEDULING

#DefMemPerCPU=0
#MaxMemPerCPU=0
#SchedulerTimeSlice=30
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core

## JOB PRIORITY

#PriorityFlags=
#PriorityType=priority/basic
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=
#PriorityCalcPeriod=
#PriorityFavorSmall=
#PriorityMaxAge=
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=
#PriorityWeightAge=
#PriorityWeightFairshare=
#PriorityWeightJobSize=
#PriorityWeightPartition=
#PriorityWeightQOS=

## LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING

#AccountingStorageEnforce=0
#AccountingStorageHost=
#AccountingStorageLoc=
#AccountingStoragePass=
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/filetxt
#AccountingStorageUser=
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=cluster
#DebugFlags=
JobCompHost=localhost
JobCompLoc=slurm_acct_db
JobCompPass=password
#JobCompPort=
JobCompType=jobcomp/mysql
JobCompUser=slurm
#JobContainerType=job_container/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=info
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=info
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#SlurmSchedLogFile=
#SlurmSchedLogLevel=

## POWER SAVE SUPPORT FOR IDLE NODES (optional)

#SuspendProgram=
#ResumeProgram=
#SuspendTimeout=
#ResumeTimeout=
#ResumeRate=
#SuspendExcNodes=
#SuspendExcParts=
#SuspendRate=
#SuspendTime=

## COMPUTE NODES

NodeName=node-[1-10] NodeAddr=node-[1-10] CPUs=16 RealMemory=64323 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=8 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=node-[1-10] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP

```
And the following is my slurmdbd.conf file:

AuthType=auth/munge
AuthInfo=/run/munge/munge.socket.2
DbdHost=localhost
DebugLevel=info
StorageHost=localhost
StorageLoc=slurm_acct_db
StoragePass=password
StorageType=accounting_storage/mysql
StorageUser=slurm
LogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmdbd.log
PidFile=/var/run/slurmdbd.pid
SlurmUser=slurm
```

Running pdsh -a sudo systemctl status slurmd on my compute nodes gives me the following error:

```
pdsh@node-0: node-5: ssh exited with exit code 3
node-6: ● slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
node-6:      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
node-6:      Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2020-08-11 03:52:58 UTC; 2min 45s ago
node-6:        Docs: man:slurmd(8)
node-6:     Process: 9068 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd $SLURMD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
node-6:    Main PID: 8983
node-6: 
node-6: Aug 11 03:34:09 node-6 systemd[1]: Starting Slurm node daemon...
node-6: Aug 11 03:34:09 node-6 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Supervising process 8983 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
node-6: Aug 11 03:34:09 node-6 systemd[1]: Started Slurm node daemon.
node-6: Aug 11 03:52:58 node-6 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Killing process 8983 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
node-6: Aug 11 03:52:58 node-6 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Killing process 8983 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
node-6: Aug 11 03:52:58 node-6 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Succeeded.
pdsh@node-0: node-6: ssh exited with exit code 3
```

I did not previously receive this type of error before when I had my cluster up and running, so I'm unsure of what I did or didn't do between now and last time I had it running. My guess is it's something to do with file/folder permissions, as I have found that can be quite critical when setting up. I may have missed documenting something I did previously. This is my second attempt at setting up a slurm managed cluster.

My entire workflow and scripts can be followed from my GitHub repo. If you need any other error outputs, please ask.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Brett